# 'sqlite3_api' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, sqlite, codeblocks, ubuntu-12.04

I've been learning sqlite3 programming in C++ for the first time and this error confounds me and my internet searching abilities.

Here is my code, as far as it gets before throwing an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3ext.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sqlite3 *database;
    int check;

    check = sqlite3_open("introdb3.db", &database); //error is here
}
```

I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with the libraries that are (or aren't) being linked, but I can't figure out how to make it go properly.

I'm on Ubuntu using code::blocks.

Thanks!!

Comment: `#include <sqlite3ext.h>` Why? Why not just `#include <sqlite3.h>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
#include <sqlite3ext.h>
```

write

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
```

The `sqlite3ext.h` file is only needed if you are going to write an SQLite extension - a custom function, for example. For regular database access, use `sqlite3.h`.

Comment: Thanks, that made the first problem go away but now it tells me "undefined reference to 'sqlite_open()."  I'm following a tutorial and it's formatted the same way so why it isn't working is beyond me.

Comment: Because it's `sqlite3_open()`, not `sqlite_open()`. Also, are you linking against sqlite3.lib?

Comment: Right, that's what I meant haha.  And I have it working now!  I checked Synaptic and there's no such thing as "sqlite3.lib" but I found and linked files related to libsqlite3-dev.  I added them using their relative paths and now all it working!  Thanks!!!