# How to use SQLite in C++ program using Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, sqlite, codeblocks

I'm a complete beginner with Code::Blocks and SQLite, and have some basic knowledge with C++. I'm currently using Ubuntu 11.04.

I have downloaded SQLite Amalgamation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html/). When I extracted the zip file, there are four files inside: `shell.c`, `sqlite3.c`, `sqlite3.h`, and `sqlite3ext.h`. If I simply add those files to a (for example) a console project, it gives out an error: the .c's of the downloaded sqlite each have their own main function. Removing those from the project, the errors are gone and I can call `#include "sqlite3.h"`. I am trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229862/sqlite3-api-was-not-declared-in-this-scope), and tried the first two lines of code from [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/122300-sqlite-in-c/) and it gives out an error: `undefined reference to sqlite3_open`.

I think adding those .h's directly to a console project isn't the right way to use it, though I'm not sure.

How exactly should I use those? What should I do to use those for my C++ program?

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

EDIT: I also tried to create a .a file of those sqlite files by following [this](http://turrier.fr/tutoriels/c_05/create-and-use-a-static-library-with-c-or-c++.html). When I try it, it gives out an error: `cannot find -lsqlite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to compile the sqlite code first, and then just `#include "sqlite3.h"` into your project where you need it.

**UPD:**
Try this:

Download [this package](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-autoconf-3071300.tar.gz) from sqlite site and extract it somewhere, say, into a folder called "sqlite". Open terminal, and go into this folder. Inside of it, run

```
./configure
sudo make 
sudo make install
```

and see what happens. It should build itself automatically. Consult the README file that is inside the archive too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) ..though I don't know how to compile it.. Do I just add it to some project and 'build project'?

Comment: Thanks :) Though I already fixed it before I read this.. :( Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 5):

I got it! Though there was something that I did that caused problems.. I forget to remove the .a file that I added at Project > Build Options > Linker Settings earlier, which caused problems..

Here are the steps I made to add SQLite: (for those that might have the same problems)

1. Copy the files extracted from the SQLite Amalgamation to the directory of the project.
2. Add the sqlite files (Project > Add Files) EXCEPT the shell.c (it is the one that causes the multiple function error)
3. Compile it (Yes, a simple Ctrl+f9).
4. here are errors: `undefined reference to pthread_mutexattr....`. These are fixed by going to Project > Build Options > Highlight 'the Project Name' above `Debug` and `Release` at the top left corner > Linker settings, and adding `"-lpthread"` (without quotes) to `Other linker options:`.
5. Some more errors are found: `undefined reference to dlopen, dlerror....`. Add '"-ldl"' just below the '"-lpthread"' added earlier.

DONE :)

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find a complete answer for Windows as a beginner, and at the beginning it is very painful to understand everything. So here's what worked for me.

1. Download the SQlite [Amalgamation](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) file.
2. Open Code::Blocks -> New Project -> Choose static library
3. Unzip the file you have downloaded and copy the folder/contents to your new project directory. Add all the files to the project and **build the project**.
4. You will find a *ProjectName*.a file in the bin/Debug or bin/Release directory. Copy that file to your actual SQlite project directory.
5. Go to Code::Blocks Project->Build options. Select 'Linker Settings' tab and add the path to the .a file. Don't close it yet!!!
6. In 'Search Directories' tab, select the 'Compiler' tab, add the path to the Amalgamation header files, or copy the header files to your directory (you can  add the header files to your project) and in the 'Linker' tab add the path to the .a file
7. Now Compile!!! Hopefully this will run

That is all, I wish it'll save some searching time for another noob