# C++ sqlite3 api is not defined (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c++, sqlite

so i wanted to mess around a bit, just to learn and stuff, but now i get an error, that "sqlite3_api" is not defined.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include "sqlite3ext.h"

using namespace std;

#define DB "dumpshit.s3db"

bool isOpenDB = false;
sqlite3 *db;

bool ConnectDB();

bool ConnectDB()
{
    if (sqlite3_open(DB, &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        isOpenDB = true;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

That is literally everything in that test file right now. I also added the sqlite3.c to my source files and sqlite3.h + sqlite3ext.h to my header files.

Why am i getting that error message?

Comment: Unless this isn't C++, you need a `main` procedure. Including the **exact** error message is also required. And you need to answer the question, why you *"added the sqlite3.c to your source files"*. You don't need that. You have precompiled binaries.

Comment: remove #include "sqlite3ext.h"

Comment: With main procedure you mean "int main(int argc, char **argv)"? Because i didn`t even get that far without that error message. As i said, the code above is literally everything..

//EDIT:
Removing that include made it, thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['sqlite3\_api' was not declared in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229862/sqlite3-api-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to include `sqlite3ext.h` file.
Just include the `sqlite3.h` file and add the `sqlite3.c` file in the Source File folder and compile the program, the program will be executed without any error.

**Here is the sample code which i have written and it's working:**

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
sqlite3 *db;    
sqlite3_stmt *res;
int rec;
/* Opening Database. */
int rec = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
/* Preparing the query */    
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "create table tb1 (col1 text, col2 text, col3 int)", -1, &res, 0);
 /* Evaluating the statement. */
sqlite3_step(res);    
/* Closing Database. */
sqlite3_close(db);

return 0;
}
```

Hope it helped..!!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem while developing an extension, so simply removing `#include "sqlite3ext.h"` was not a workable solution for me.

What did work was the following, from "4. Programming Loadable Extensions", of sqlite's [Run-Time Loadable Extensions](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html) documentation.

> 2. Put the macro "SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT1" on a line by itself right after the "#include <sqlite3ext.h>" line.

So:

```
#include "sqlite3ext.h"
SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT1
```

worked to fix the error.

Comment: It's workable either for `#include <winsqlite/winsqlite3ext.h>`, yes windows sdk includes this sqlite lib too.